# Why is this Ajax conditional dialog not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, client-side-scripting

Why is this code not working?

In the meantime (trying to make it work) i have changed it a dosen time, but i can't find the solution.

Anyone has an idea? I have no errors in console.

First of all, it check's if a dialog needs to be opened.

This is the workflow:

If DialogRequired => Dialog.Click = OK --> execute an ajax call 
If DialogRequired => Dialog.Click = Cancel  --> do nothing
If Dialog NOT Required => execute an ajax call

```
$(function () {
    $("a.orderlink").unbind();

    $("a.orderlink").bind("click", function () {
        var ProductID = $(this).parent().attr("data-productid");
        var Ammount = $(this).parent().parent().find("input#ammount").val();

        $.ajax({ type: "post",
            url: $(this).attr("href").replace("AddToCart", "ExistsInCart"),
            data: { ProductId: $(this).parent().attr("data-productid") },
            succes: function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    $("#ProductExistsInOrder").dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        height: 170,
                        width: 400,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "OK": function () {
                                /*acties om toe te voegen $.ajax()*/
                                $.ajax({ type: "post",
                                    url: $(this).attr("href"),
                                    data: { ProductId: ProductID, Ammount: Ammount },
                                    succes: function () {
                                        $("#AddProductNotification").text("U heeft net een product toegevoegd. Herlaad de pagina om uw winkelwagentje te bekijken");
                                    }
                                });
                                setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 100);
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                location.reload(true);
                            //    return false;
                            },
                            "Annuleer": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                             //   return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $.ajax({ type: "post",
                        url: $(this).attr("href"),
                        data: { ProductId: ProductID, Ammount: Ammount },
                        succes: function () {
                            $("#AddProductNotification").text("U heeft net een product toegevoegd. Herlaad de pagina om uw winkelwagentje te bekijken");
                        }
                    });


                };
                // $("#AddProductNotification").text("U heeft net een product toegevoegd. Herlaad de pagina om uw winkelwagentje te bekijken");
            },
            error: function (XMLHeeptRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        // alert("end");
        //  AddToCart(this);
        return false;
    });
   // return false;
});
// ProductId: $(orderlinkObject).parent().attr("data-productid"), Ammount: $(orderlinkObject).parent().parent().find("input#ammount").val()
```

This is how it goes:

- Gets called (=ok) : /Cart/ExistsInCart with parameter: product ID and returns true in jSon
- But the dialog isn't called and i can't seem to update it with firebug.

Comment: does it throw any error?

Comment: What is not working? and What is working?

Comment: Please define "not working".  What is the code supposed to do, what is it actually doing and are there any errors on your console.

Comment: Are you debugging it? Why don't you handle the completed event of the ajax calls and verify that they are both returning OK?

Comment: 'succes' in your ajax object should be spelled success.

Comment: If you can locate a specific place in your code where something fails to happen the way it's supposed to, I'm sure we can help.  (If you don't find it just by narrowing down the point of failure.)

Comment: This is an overly complicated sample of code with too many basic errors to really qualify as a good question.

Comment: Dude, serious. I have used succes like 4 times instead of success. it was only used as submitting values and not retrieving values.

So i didn't notice as i thought i used it prior to this. But damn, seemce like a just used copy-past with no thinking. Really an idiotic mistake :s

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having problems with your scope.

You have alot of `$(this).attr("href")` in anonymous functions in ajax success.  In those function `this != "a.orderlink"`.

You will want to do `var that = $(this)` up at the top of your click handler and then use `that.attr("href")`.

Example: http://jsbin.com/ivoniv/edit#javascript

Comment: Updated my question. By coïncidence, i had also changed the href to a var in the start. But this hasn't helped me.